# How do i display a message to the user when his cart is empty,Am using RecyclerAdapter to display the carts items

Tags: android

How do i display a message to the user when his cart is empty. The item in the cart are being displayed using Recycle View Adapter. My cart_activity file which contains Recycle View and Text View.
I have never done this before, I will grateful if someone can help.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cartList"
        android:layout_width="408dp"
        android:layout_height="617dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CurrentCartStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firsttime"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="You have no item in the cart"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
```

My CartActivity.java:

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private TextView cartStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.cartList);
        cartStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentCartStatus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your card arrayList size. If your card arrayList size is < 0 then gone the visibility of recyclerView and visible the this `CurrentCartStatus`. If your card ArrayList size is > 0 then hide the textView and visible the recyclerView.

**Check below example.**

```
if (cardArrayList.size() > 0) {            
    CurrentCartStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    adapter.addData(cardArrayList);
} else {
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    CurrentCartStatus.setText("No data available");
    CurrentCartStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```